# Incompatible types. Found: 'void', required: 'int' but whats wrong?

Tags: java

```
public class MegaBytesConverter {
    public static int printMegaBytesAndKiloBytes(int kiloBytes) {
        if (kiloBytes < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Value");
            return -1;
        } else { int megaBYTES=(kiloBytes/1024);
           int remainderKiloBytes=(kiloBytes%1024);
           return System.out.println(kiloBytes+" KB"+"="+megaBYTES+"MB"+"AND"+remainderKiloBytes+"KB");
        }
    }
}
```

why it is telling found void in return statement when i  have already specified it as int?

Comment: The `println` method doesn't return a value.  Therefore you can't use its "value" as the return value of some other method.

Comment: so you mean i have to create new variable

Comment: You cannot `return System.out.println` because that's a `void` expression, which means it returns nothing itself. Your method is declared to return an `int` (`public static int`) but its name tells a user it just prints something (`printMegaBytesAndKiloBytes`). If this method is to print some result of a conversion, you could make it `public static void printMegaBytesAndKiloBytes` and just remove the line `return -1;` and the keyword `return` before `System.out.println(kiloBytes+.-..`.

Comment: Not necessarily.  What you really need to do is to read what you have written, and ask yourself if it actually makes sense.  That last statement needs to return an integer, but it looks more like nonsense to me.

Comment: but i have to keep in int not void to test it in main class in intelliJ

Comment: Yes. But you have to return an `int`.   Read the code that you have written, and *think about what it actually means*.

Comment: new to programming need some time to think..

Comment: Take your time to think then.

Comment: yeah i got print statement returns noting and i was asking it to return int.

Comment: your patience is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println()` returns void, your method expects an `int` to be returned currently, instead you could make your method return a `String`:

```
public class MegaBytesConverter {
    public static String getMegaBytesAndKiloBytes(int kiloBytes) {
        if (kiloBytes < 0) {
            return "Invalid kiloBytes value";
        }
        int megaBytes = kiloBytes / 1024;
        int remainderKiloBytes = kiloBytes % 1024;
        return String.format("%dMB and %dKB%n", megaBytes, remainderKiloBytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int kiloBytes = 1098;
        System.out.printf("%dKB = %s%n", kiloBytes, getMegaBytesAndKiloBytes(kiloBytes));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1098KB = 1MB and 74KB
```